# Lambda Method Query Syntax with a List within a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have my model as:

```
// Person
public class Person {
    public int Id {get; set}
    public string FirstName {get; set}
    public string LastName {get; set}
    public ICollection<PersonCourse> PersonCourses {get; set;}
}
// PersonCourse
public class PersonCourse {
    public int PersonId {get; set}
    public Person Person {get; set;}
    public int CourseId {get; set}
    public Course Course {get; set}
}
// Course
public class Course {
    public int Id {get; set}
    public string Name {get; set}
    public ICollection<PersonCourse> PersonCourses {get; set;}
}
```

I have the following data:

```
// Person
ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
1  John      Doe
2  Jane      Doe

// PersonCourse
PersonId CourseId
1        1
1        2
2        1
2        3

// Course
ID NAME
1  Course1
2  Course2
3  Course3
```

How can I write a Lambda Method query to get the data as an `IEnumerable` as:

```
John Doe Course1
John Doe Course2
Jane Doe Course1
Jane Doe Course3
```

Currently, I have the courses listed in a CSV format like below:

```
// NOTE:
// MUST start query from DBSet<Person> not from DBSet<PersonCourse>!
var data = db.Persons.Select(x => new {
    FirstName = x.FirstName,
    LastName = x.LastName,
    CourseName = string.Join(",", x.PersonCourses.Select(c => c.Course.Name)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for this is:

```
var data = db.Persons.SelectMany(c => c.PersonCourses.Select(x => c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName + " " + x.Course.Name));
```

Assuming that everything is not null. I prefer always to manage Null safety, but that depends on the final result that you want (discard if is a single null or fill with empty string)

Comment: #Beautiful! I see my mistake and forgot about `SelectMany()` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple rows per `Person` you need a `Join` or a `SelectMany`.

Using the navigation properties you can do this:

```
var data = db.Persons.SelectMany
    (
        p => p.PersonCourses,
        (p, pc) => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, pc.Course.Name }
    );
```

Or you can do the uglier but more general join, avoiding the navigation properties:

```
var data = db.Persons
    .Join
    (
        db.PersonCourses, p => p.Id, pc => pc.PersonId, 
        (p, pc) => new { p, pc }
    )
    .Join
    (
        db.Courses, j => j.pc.CourseId, c => c.Id, 
        (j, c) => new { j.p.FirstName, jn.p.LastName, c.Name }
    );
```

Joins work when the navigation properties aren't available (POCOs in memory for instance) and aren't all that hard to work with... except for that pesky intermediate `j` but you get used to it.